# torch.distributed.get_world_size() and torch.cuda.device_count() returning different numbers, getting invalid device ordinal error

Tags: python, pytorch, parallel-processing, slurm

I'm trying to used tensor parallelization across multiple GPUs in pytorch, specifically 2 Nvidia A100s, to spread a model which is too big for one GPU across multiple using a slurm-based HPC. I'm having trouble with my model so I generated this small toy example (adapted from [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/question-about-tensor-parallel-dtensor-parallelize-module/181739)) to illustrate the main issue. All work so far has been done on a jupyter notebook.

I'm new to parallelization as a whole. My understanding is that to spread a model across a number of GPUs I should set each shard of the model to a different GPU, with the total number of GPUs being the number of processes, assuming no multithreading. However, when I run `torch.distributed.get_world_size()`, I get a different result from when I run `torch.cuda.device_count()`.

```py
from torch.distributed.tensor.parallel import (
    PairwiseParallel,
    parallelize_module,
)

import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.distributed as dist
from torch.distributed._tensor import DeviceMesh #, DTensor, Shard, Replicate, distribute_tensor

from torch.testing._internal.common_distributed import (
    spawn_threads_and_init_comms,
)

class ToyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, hidden_channels):
        super(ToyModel, self).__init__()
        self.dummy_param = nn.Parameter(torch.empty(0))
        self.net1 = nn.Linear(in_channels, hidden_channels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.net2 = nn.Linear(hidden_channels, in_channels)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net2(self.relu(self.net1(x)))
        
@spawn_threads_and_init_comms
def demo_world_rank_mismatch(world_size):
    rank = dist.get_rank()
    print(f'Rank: {rank}')

    print(f"World size: {dist.get_world_size()}")

    print("Create a sharding plan based on the given world_size", world_size)

    mesh = torch.arange(world_size)
    # create a sharding plan based on the given world_size.
    device_mesh = DeviceMesh(
        "cuda",
        mesh,
    )
    in_dim = 1024
    hidden_dim = 4 * in_dim

    model = ToyModel(in_dim, hidden_dim).to(rank)

    # Create a optimizer for the parallelized module.
    LR = 0.25
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=LR)

    lparallel=True
    if lparallel:
        print("Parallelize the module based on the given Parallel Style", rank)
        model = parallelize_module(model, device_mesh, PairwiseParallel())
    print(model)

    print(f"model of rank {rank} on {model.dummy_param.device}")

    # Perform a num of iterations of forward/backward
    # and optimizations for the sharded module.
    for i in range(ITER_TIME):
        inp = torch.rand(10000, in_dim).to(rank)
        output = model(inp)
        #print(f"FWD Step: iter {i}", rank)
        output.sum().backward()
        #print(f"BWD Step: iter {i}", rank)
        optimizer.step()
        #print(f"Optimization Step: iter {i}", rank)
    
    #print("Training finished", rank)
    print(f'{rank}, max memory alloc: {torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated(device=rank)}')


print(f"Device count: {torch.cuda.device_count()}")
demo_world_rank_mismatch(torch.cuda.device_count())
```

Running this code outputs the following

```
Device count: 2
Rank: 1
World size: 4
Create a sharding plan based on the given world_size 2
Rank: 2
World size: 4
Create a sharding plan based on the given world_size 2
Rank: 3
World size: 4
Create a sharding plan based on the given world_size 2
Rank: 0
World size: 4
Create a sharding plan based on the given world_size 2
Parallelize the module based on the given Parallel Style 0
Parallelize the module based on the given Parallel Style 1
```

And then it outputs a gigantic error message, much of which is repeated from the multiple threads exiting, and the last bit of which is here:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.
```

Pytorch version is 2.1.0+cu121. I'm at a lost as to where to go from here.

Comment: I see you are new to parallel training. You should probably look for [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html) tutorial. Let `DataParallel` handle everything. You don't need tensor parallelization framework for this job.

Comment: Prakhar Sharma this does not fix my problem. Calling nvidia-smi after the cell running the model crashes shows that the only GPU with anything stored on it is the first one (rank 0).